# Does a curve which is homeomorphic to interval always have a finite length independent of the parametrization in general metric spaces?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, curves, algebraic-curves

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space and $C\subseteq X$ be a subset which is homeomorphic to interval $[a,b]$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R},a<b$. Each homeomorphism $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow C$ is called a parametrization. Is it true that each parametrization has finite length, which is the same for all parametrizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given such a curve $\gamma:\>[a,b]\to X$ and a partition
$${\cal P}:\quad a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_N=b$$
of the interval $[a,b]$ let
$$\ell_{\cal P}(\gamma):=\sum_{k=1}^N d\bigl(\gamma(t_{k-1}),\gamma(t_k)\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$
The *length* $L(\gamma)$ is then defined as
$$L(\gamma):=\sup_{\cal P}\ell_{\cal P}(\gamma)\leq\infty\ .$$
The value $L(\gamma)$ remains unchanged under a homeomorphism of $[a,b]$ (or some other reparametrization), because the collection of sums $(1)$ remains the same. For an example with $L(\gamma)=\infty$ consider 
$$\gamma:\quad[0,1]\to{\mathbb R}^2,\qquad t\mapsto\left(t,\  t\,\sin{1\over t}\right)\qquad(t>0),\qquad \gamma(0):=(0,0)\ .$$

Comment: You gave an example of a curve which is not rectifiable, but in my question I consider some special curves. Namely those for which parametrization is not only continuous but is a homeomorphism. I think your example does not satisfy this condition.

Comment: Also the fact that the value $L(\gamma)$ remains the same under a homeomophism doesn't answer my question, because I ask whether $L(\gamma_1)=L(\gamma_2)$ for two different parametrization of the same set $C$.

Comment: @Kulisty The parametrization of that non-rectifiable curve certinaly is a homeomorphism. Any 1-1 parametrization of a curve is a homemorphism! II $X$ is compact, $Y$ is hausdorff and $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous bijection then $f^{-1}$ is continuous. (Proof: Say $O\subset X$ is open. Then $K=X\setminus O$ is compact. So $f(K)$ is compact. Hence $f(K)$ is closed, so $f(O)$ is open.)

Comment: You're absolutely right ! I think I see the argument for equality $L(\gamma_1)=L(\gamma_2)$ as well (define $h:=\gamma_1^{-1}\circ\gamma_2$, then  $h$ is a homeomorphism and $\gamma_1\circ h=\gamma_2$)

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. If $\gamma$ has finite length, then it is called *rectifiable*. See https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Rectifiable_curve. A non-rectifiable example is

$$c : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2, c(t) =
\begin{cases} 
(t,t\cos(\pi/t) & t > 0  \\
(0,0)  & t = 0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Is the image of $c$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$? Is is something more than just continuity.

Comment: In fact  had a typo ($\cos(\pi/t)$ instead of the correct $t\cos(\pi/t)$). The "correct" $c$ is a continuous bijection from $[0,1]$ to $c([0,1])$ and thefore a homeorphism because $[0,1]$ is compact and $c([0,1])$ is Hausdorff.